# Excel formula -> how to change SUMPRODUCT formula to skip null cells

Tags: excel-formula

**context is**
I am using adjusted sumproduct formula to calculate weighted average.

**problem is** 
sumproduct includes empty cells in arrays. => weighted average is calculated incorrectly.

**question is**
How to edit sumproduct to exclude empty cells in arrays?

**alternatively**
Is there another clean and neat solution?

Comment: You can normally solve this kind of thing using arrays. Could you post your current formula so I can gauge its complexity?

Answer (score 7):

In the sumproduct, to exclude empty cells, suppose you're using it on range A1:A100, you could do the following:

```
= Sumproduct((A1:A100),--(A1:A100<>""))
```

That second criteria will ensure that you're only looking at cells that have a value in them...

As an explanation (A1:A100<>"") will return an array of `True` `False`, where, if there is a value in the cell, it returns true, otherwise, false. Then, including the `--` before it, it converts True/False to 1/0. So, in effect, you're multiplying empty cells by a zero (excluding from the formula) and non-empty cells by 1 (including them in the formula).

The `--(logical statement for my array)` is a very useful trick to use with SumProduct() in MANY different ways!!