# Sum Product Errors in Excel Errors

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, formula, product

I have this formula and it is giving me grief, I keep getting errors (#DIV/0!). I have checked online and apparently sum product does not like blanks. I was wondering if someone could help me out on how I can get sumproduct to skip the blank cells.

=SUMPRODUCT((N2:N8/M2:M8>85)*(M2:M8))

Basically column M is a list of orders while N is a list of the total weight of those orders. I need to sum the orders column if (Charge Weight/Orders) is greater than 85. so basically IF CHARGE WEIGHT "divided by" ORDERS>85 then sum. Hopefully this makes sense.

Also Note, this is just a sample data, the actual data can be thousands and thousands of rows.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel formula -> how to change SUMPRODUCT formula to skip null cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609922/excel-formula-how-to-change-sumproduct-formula-to-skip-null-cells).  Also did you [search for anything first?](https://www.google.com/search?q=sumproduct+to+skip+the+blank+cells)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it before posting and it's not providing me with the answer I needed. I responded to another person with more information RE my question.

Comment: To start, _"I keep getting errors"_: The reason you get these errors are not to annoy you - they are there to provide you **useful information**. And because this information is **useful**, it would also help us with your question. So please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what errors you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my question. Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of ways of doing it, the simplest one would be:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(((ChargeWeight/Shippers)>85),0)*(Shippers))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but its not providing me with the result that I would like. apologies, I didn't provide you with all the information. Basically column M is a list of orders while N is a list of the total weight of those orders. I need to sum the orders column if (Charge Weight/Orders) is greater than 85. so basically IF CHARGE WEIGHT/ORDERS>85 then sum. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Corrected, please test.  It's an array formula, so enter with Ctrl-Shift